# In the linux boot commands, what does edd=on and nolapic do?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, boot

I am running Ubuntu and had this issue where one day the system just decided not to boot.  I wandered around blindly, and somehow came across these two little parameters.   Now, each time if I type edd=on and nolapic to the linux line of the boot commands, the system boots as it should.

What is this edd=on and nolapic, and why do I need to type these custom commands to boot into Ubuntu linux? I feel like if I understand what they mean I can understand the problem, and maybe fix it forever.

PS:  what is the name for the list of boot commands I am referring to?  Is it just the "boot command list", or "bootload script"?  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDD BIOS Enhanced Disk Drive Services,
APIC Advanced Programmable Interrupt Controller

```
noapic      [SMP,APIC] Tells the kernel to not make use of any
            IOAPICs that may be present in the system.



edd=        [EDD]
            Format: {"off" | "on" | "skip[mbr]"}
```

You can find details in your distribution's documentation (ubuntu) and in the online [documentation of the kernel’s command-line parameters](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/latest/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)